# Connecting to dynamically created child scope connects elsewhere

Tags: flash, red5

I am new to Red5 and very desperate to know the following.

I have an application in which, when a client connects to it, a child scope is created and then the client is made to connect to that child scope. The following code represents this:

```
@Override
public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {

    createChildScope(scopeName);

    super.connect(conn, getChildScope(scopeName), params);

    return true;
}
```

What I have discovered is that even though the child scope is passed as parameter to the `connect` method, the connection is being made to the application scope of my application.

Instead of `super.connect(conn, getChildScope(scopeName), params);`, I have tried:

```
getChildScope(scopeName).connect(conn, params);
```

and

```
conn.connect(getChildScope(scopeName), params);
```

but both of these have failed and returned `false`.

Tests that I have performed to know that the connection is being made to the application scope instead of to the child scope are as follows:

1)

```
System.out.println(getConnections().size());
System.out.println(getChildScope(scopeName).getClientConnections().size());
```

which gave:

```
1
0
```

2)

```
@Override
public boolean roomConnect(IConnection conn, Object[] params){
    System.out.println("Connected to room " + conn.getScope());
    return super.roomConnect(conn, params);
}
```

which gave:

```
Connected to room Scope [name=Group Discussion Server, path=/default, type=APPLICATION, autoStart=true, creationTime=1453042388349, depth=1, enabled=true, running=true]
```

which is really weird as the `connect` method is actually determining that the connection needs to be made to a room scope, but it is being made to the application scope.

I tried allowing the Red5 server to automatically create the scope via:

```
nc.connect("rtmp://Server/scopeName");
```

in my Flash application, and this worked perfectly fine.

Please let me have an idea about what is happening.

Thank you.